# What does "derived from" mean in copyright?

Tags: copyright, definition

In copyright law the right to create a derivative work is restricted to the copyright holder.  [The definition of derivative work from the US Copyright office seems a little circular](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf):

> A derivative work is a work based on or derived from one or more already existing works.

What does this mean in practice?  Is it purely a description of the process, or is the result and/or motivation relevant?

If we consider a hypothetical, set next year when Steamboat Willie is out of copyright but the more familiar Mickey of Fantasia is not.  Suppose Alice takes the image of mickey from Steamboat Willie, automatically applies a large number of image transforms to that image (these days I guess one would use [style transfer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer), but I am sure it could be done with simple [GIMP macros](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Automate_Editing_in_GIMP/)).  This results in thousands of versions of Mickey Mouse, some very similar to the famous red shorts and white gloves, and all results are released publically under CC0..  Suppose Bob looks at all the resulting versions and selects the one that looks most like the still copyrighted image.  He then goes on to create an artistic work using this image.  Is the resulting work a derivative of the later Mickey Mouse work, even though it was created with no input from the later work?  Suppose the work does not raise trademark issues for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Not really.  That answer comes down to the same definition I quote, "under the US definition, a derivative work is one based on an earlier work".  It does not define "based on" as meaning the technical sense I describe or something else.

Comment: In the law, the paragraph seems to define "based upon" implicitly with examples -- A “derivative work” is a work based upon one or more preexisting works, such as a translation, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization, motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment, condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast, transformed, or adapted.

Comment: For the Tensorflow filter, it seems to depend whether this is considered "based on" the materials under which that filter is trained. For example, if you train the neural style filter by giving it lots of images of current Mickey Mouse images (with current copyrights), then perhaps the results using that neural style transfer filter on a different image will then be considered to be based upon that training data (i.e. maybe it's a sort of adaptation, or "any other form in which a work may be recast"). I don't think this is a settled issue in law. Find out more by searching the site for 'AI'.